# Calculate growing degree days using NetCDF file in R

Tags: r, netcdf, maps

I have a NetCDF file containing temperature values over a certain region from 1984 - 1985, with 1-hour intervals, so that means that I have 17544 maps. I need to do two things and I got a bit stuck with this:

1. I need to calculate the months sequence between frost (growing season) for each place as the region I am studying has very different altitudes.
2. Also I would like to have one NetCDF with the maximum temperatures per day during the growing seasons to calculate an accumulated GDD only with that months.

My NetCDF atrributes are:

```
     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        short t2m[longitude,latitude,time]   
            scale_factor: 0.000887995489644173
            add_offset: 281.136694368954
            _FillValue: -32767
            missing_value: -32767
            units: K
            long_name: 2 metre temperature

     3 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:21
            units: degrees_east
            long_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:21
            units: degrees_north
            long_name: latitude
        time  Size:17544
            units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0
            long_name: time
            calendar: gregorian
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. "Also" and bullet lists of questions are closure bait. Please [Edit] your Question to ask one question, and to include the code you've developed to attempt this task.